# How to export a chart in apex?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

The problem is as old as I know Apex :) (which is more or less a year)
Base a several charts made in APEX I every week has to create a presentation in PowerPoint. It is time consuming because I need to do a screenshot of every chart, save it then rescale it and finally paste it to PPoint.
I want to improve it/automatise it. Is this any way to save existing chart (region with chart) to file/clipboard direct from APEX?

Comment: Added a new solution to my answer, check it out. I hope this one works for you.

Comment: well,  I have just looked at fetures in APEX 20.2 and ... the funcionality I need has been implemented :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AOP plugin is best, but its only free for 30 copies a month. Depending on how many charts you are printing each week, it might do. The 1000 copies a month costs 29 eur a month, which to just help you, is probably too much.

You can also do some built in printing with BI Publisher files I believe, but I have never used it so I cant help you there.

You could also just download each report as a .cvs and set up a script to print those.

From what I heard, its also not that difficult to just make new account for AOP so you could do a free account, and when it runs out just open a new account.

EDIT:
Was researching other things today and stumbled upon a free solution you might like. I havent tried it yet, basically just found it. But I hope its what you are looking for: https://menn.ooo/interactive-grid-download-as-pdf-with-jspdf/

Comment: if you say "The AOP plugin is best" there are probably others plugin's with similiar funcionality.  The only think I need is to save graph (region with graph) into file or copy region into clipboard.

Comment: There might be other plugins.
If the formating isnt that important the best would be saving into .cvs and then printing the excel

Comment: @your EDIT:   That's it !!  well it does not export to jpeg but pdf , it does not export region but interactive grid but it is exacly the solution I'm looking for - simple button , simple save window and noting more. There is a source code so I believe with a small help of my colleagues programmers (I wish I could know JavaScript) I am able to modify in the way I need it  **TinoO **- thanks very much for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with the AOP plug in

[Aop Plugin](https://www.apexofficeprint.com/index.html)

Comment: well, after a quick look ... it could be a good solution.  Unfortunately it is not free :(